# CSS bug with Image on responsive web page

Tags: html, css

I have a bug in my CSS when it comes to a responsive page with images.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xr4getom/

You'll notice on this example that a dark background (`#222`) appears at times when you resize the window. Is there a fix for this that would just force the image to take up this area - while keeping the ratio correct?

I have omitted the CSS from here as it goes over the character limit but if you click the demo link, you can see it.

```html
  <section class="news-bloc">
 <div class="news-container">
  <h1>Latest News</h1>
  <ul class="news-list">
   <li>
    <a href='#' target='_blank'><img alt='' class='img-responsive photo-thumb image-link' src='https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/c157.0.406.406/14504934_1825657564379158_1219547695887155200_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTQwMDU3NTA0ODg3NjAyNTIxNA%3D%3D.2.c'>
    <p>View Post</p></a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! :-)

```
ul.news-list>li>a {     
    width: 100%;        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the image in the background of your `<a>` instead of using `<img>` tag. Like:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="news-list">
  <li>
    <a href='#' target='_blank' style="background-image: url('https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/c157.0.406.406/14504934_1825657564379158_1219547695887155200_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTQwMDU3NTA0ODg3NjAyNTIxNA%3D%3D.2.c');">
      <p>View Post</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.news-list li a {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Have a look at this **[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xr4getom/2/)**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Yes! because this will keep the ratio of all the images same without distorting the image. Also don't mind accepting this as your answer if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, Saurav - I'm going to test this out and if no other better answers come in, I will accept. Many, many thanks again :-)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk No issues. Its my pleasure. Always happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `<li>` element is having width more than that of image. Try setting your li width to `auto` -

```
ul.news-list li {
float: left;
width: auto;   <-- Changed here
margin-right: 1.63934%;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 1.63934%;
background-color: #222
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use margin-bottom:-5px; in the css code

Comment: and also if you have used your div width and height  is equal to 200px make your image width and height 200px as well